# Spring Boot Serving a pdf but it opens in the browser as a blank pdf

Tags: javascript, spring-boot

I am trying to send a generated PDF through my Spring controller, which I've verified it looks fine when I save it as a file on the server and open it. When I send the request, it opens up a new tab and the pdf is blank.  Has correct number of pages and everything, just is blank.

I've saved the PDF from the browser and compared it to the one generated and saved on the server, and the one from the browser is larger, which makes me believe that the encoding is wrong. But I've looked at a lot of other Spring controller examples of sending PDF's and I have code that does the same thing as theirs.  The controller sends back a ResponseEntity (I've also tried ResponseEntity)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generatePDF", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> generatePDF(@RequestBody UserObject userObject) {

        //Generation of PDF

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
        headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", "document.pdf");
        headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        try {
            File file = new File("/path/to/document.pdf");
            byte[] filecontent = Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath());
            return new ResponseEntity(filecontent,headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The javascript that makes the request is:

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "myURL",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data : JSON.stringify(data),
            async: false,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                window.open(URL.createObjectURL(new File([response], "document.pdf")));
            }
        });
```

A new tab opens, but the pdf is blank and the binary data looks different between the one saved on the server and what is downloaded from the browser

Comment: Hello, Try by adding headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename); and let me know the results

Answer (score 0):

Try Following by adding `headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);`

```
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    headers.setContentDispositionFormData("inline", "document.pdf");
    headers.add("content-disposition", "inline;filename=" + filename);   
    headers.setCacheControl("must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
```